# MikroC Hardware Interrupt

Tags: pic, c, interrupts, hardware

I am trying to program a PIC 16F876A using mikroC. I need the program to run when I push a button to a certain point, stop and wait till the button is pushed again before finishing.

```
void interrupt() // ISR 
{ 
 INTCON.INTF=0; // Clear the interrupt 0 flag 
 PORTC=~PORTC; // Invert (Toggle) the value at PortD 
 Delay_ms(1000); // Delay for 1 sec 
}
```

I have read that using a hardware interrupt is the way to do this but can not get mine to work.

Comment: Could you please post your interrupt code that is currently not working?

Comment: Sorry Blup I as it wasn't working I didn't save it beofore I closed MikroC. It was something like,

void interrupt() //  ISR
{
 INTCON.INTF=0; // Clear the interrupt 0 flag
 PORTC=~PORTC; // Invert (Toggle) the value at PortD
 Delay_ms(1000); // Delay for 1 sec
}

Comment: Sorry hit enter and it posted.
Got it now.. I needed the whole program to pause, or wait for the button to be pushed before continuing, any ideas?

Comment: Please add your code into the question body (with the code formatting). Reading a piece of code in a comment is not easy.

Comment: Don't call delay functions from inside an ISR.

Comment: Contrary to what you said, interrupts vectors are not the only way to do it. You can use the interrupt flag and check it on a state machine, depending on the type of application this can be more efficient or not. Anyway from what I remember PIC mid-range have only one interrupt vector.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify what is meant by "not working", so I'll just point out a few things.

The interrupt service routine posted does not seem to address the program function described.  This routine toggles a port, waits a second, then goes back to whatever was running before the interrupt was triggered.  Instead you say you want the program to wait for a button press, then do something, then wait for another button press.

If the program is doing nothing but waiting for an input, you don't really need an interrupt, just a polling loop.  Interrupts should be used when you need to quickly respond to an event, or do something at a precise time.  ISRs should finish quickly; never should one include a one second delay.

Another thing to consider: There is more to using an interrupt than writing an ISR.  I'm not familiar with mikroC, but in general you will need to at least set up an interrupt vector, configure the I/O or peripheral to generate an interrupt, and enable interrupts. Have you done all this necessary initialization?

Also, upon entry to an interrupt routine, the CPU *context*, its status and registers, must be saved, and restored upon return.  Typically the compiler is alerted to this by using a keyword, often *interrupt*, in the function definition.   Does the compiler understand that this is an ISR?

Finally, make sure your watchdog doesn't timeout while you are waiting for input.

Oh, and don't forget: you may have to debounce the pushbutton.